# Html css / Images in Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 30 images , how can i put all 30 images in one section without scrolling.I am using fullpage.js library.

images Dimension is 400x400

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="container">
      <!-- images are here -->
   </div>
</div
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"scrolling"* here? Because if the screen is too small it's impossible to not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try nano gallery, its a useful image viewer for webpages 
http://nanogallery.brisbois.fr

Answer (score 0):

### A quick solution below.

### Another way can be done is to fix the image ratio, the problem is that way you must allowed scroll.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
});
```

```css
.section {
 text-align: center;
}

.fit-all {
 backgounrd-color: green;
 
}

img{
 height: calc(100%/6);
 width: calc(100%/6.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>




<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>

    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>

    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>

    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>

    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>

    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive"/>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```